# How can I simplify this sentence?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I am counting the number of questions about Drupal asked on Stack Overflow, and for my convenience I consider a question about Drupal if it contains one of the following tags:

- [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal)
- [drupal-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-5)
- [drupal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6)
- [drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7)
- [drupal-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-8)

I don't consider, for example, questions tagged [drupal-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-views) without one of the previous tags; also, I don't consider the questions tagged, for example, *drupal-7* and *drupal-8* but not *drupal*.

I give the number of questions using:

- *drupal*
- *drupal-5* but not *drupal* (since the questions using *drupal* and *drupal-5* are already counted in the first group)
- *drupal-6* but not *drupal*
- *drupal-7* but not *drupal*
- *drupal-8* but not *drupal*

I wrote the following sentence, but it seems too verbose.

> To make a comparison, [the questions tagged drupal (and not using drupal-5, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-8) on Stack Overflow are 7,474](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+-drupal-5+-drupal-6+-drupal-7+-drupal-8); to those, you need to add [2 questions tagged drupal-8 but not drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-8+-drupal), [2,062 questions tagged drupal-7 but not drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7+-drupal), [1,116 questions tagged drupal-6 but not drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6+-drupal), and [4 questions tagged drupal-5 but not drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-5+-drupal).

I could use "the questions tagged drupal," but that would not mean "questions about Drupal"; I could not say the questions tagged only with *drupal*" since those questions use also other tags, for example *drupal-views*. If I say "2,062 questions tagged drupal-7" it could not be clear if the questions are also tagged with *drupal*.

Is there a way to rephrase it using less words, and avoiding any ambiguity? For example, would the following sentence be without ambiguities?

> To make a comparison, [the questions tagged drupal on Stack Overflow are 7,474](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+-drupal-5+-drupal-6+-drupal-7+-drupal-8); to those, you need to add [2 questions tagged drupal-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-8+-drupal), [2,062 questions tagged drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7+-drupal), [1,116 questions tagged drupal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6+-drupal), and [4 questions tagged drupal-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-5+-drupal).

Comment: This is why tables were invented!

Comment: Closevoters please clarify the reason for voting. I don't think "unclear" or "opinion-based" apply here. This is a proofreading question where a specific area of concern (repeated words) has been identified, so it seems to fit within existing question guidelines. (Just because we haven't been able to come up with a good *answer* (including my own) as of yet doesn't disqualify the question). So, any closevoters want to chime in?

Comment: @WendiKidd: As previously noted, I closevoted as POB because I was influenced by StoneyB's comment and your answer. Thus it originally seemed to me the only useful response was "this information would be better expressed in tabular form". I no longer endorse that position, because I now see it as asking "how would you express this information succinctly *in speech*?".

Comment: @FumbleFingers But OP says "I **wrote** the sentence, but it seems too verbose."

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, what I meant was *in words, **but not relying on text formatting***. I still think all possible answers would be to some extent POB, but assuming we discount those where visual layout is crucial, I stand by my reopen vote on the grounds that the easiest way for OP to reduce the verbiage is to introduce the word ***respectively***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are 7,474 questions tagged **drupal**, plus version-specific questions tagged  **drupal-5, -6, -7, and -8** (but not **drupal**) with totals of 4, 1,116, 2062, and 2 respectively.

---

OP's text doesn't specify whether any questions are tagged with more than one value of **drupal-n** (but *without* the generic **drupal** tag). If there are any, it's unspecified whether/how they're counted.

Comment: To me, "tagged *only* with **drupal-5, -6, -7, and -8**" carries the meaning of "is tagged with drupal-5, drupal-6, drupal-7, and drupal-8, but has no other tags beyond these*. I think this is a tricky one (as is evidenced by our discussion that my answer isn't 100% spot-on, either!). I think it's hard to come up with a concise way to convey this much information in one sentence.

Comment: @WendiKidd: So far as I can see, OP hasn't specified whether any questions might be tagged, say, **drupal-5** *and* **drupal-6** (but *not* tagged **drupal**). If there are any like that the question text implies nothing about whether they would be "double-counted", or excluded completely from the counts as given.

Comment: I would remove _only_ from "tagged only with," since that could be understood as "those questions are not using other Drupal-related tags." For the rest, the sentence avoids repeating the same phrase, which is what I wanted. This answers my question. There is an ambiguity that cannot be resolved, but that is intrinsic in the data I collected: I cannot exclude that between those questions there are some that use drupal-6 and drupal-7, for example, even if there are very few questions using two or more drupal-N tags.

Comment: I am not expecting a question using drupal-5, drupal-6, and drupal-7 since that would actually mean all the official releases of Drupal (past and present). At that point, the question should be simply tagged drupal.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Okay - I see the original question text has been changed, so I've edited to reflect that. I still think the only important thing about the answer is that you can express this information more succinctly using the word *respectively*. And I still think the treatment of certain tag combinations is unspecified, as indicated in my revised text.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I think the simplest and clearest way to get your point across would be to use a list.

> To make a comparison, see these questions:
>
> - Those [tagged drupal, but not drupal-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+-drupal-5+-drupal-6+-drupal-7+-drupal-8) (7,474)
> - Those tagged drupal-x, but not drupal, for:
>
>   - [drupal-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-8+-drupal) (2)
>   - [drupal-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7+-drupal) (2,062)
>   - [drupal-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6+-drupal) (1,116)
>   - [drupal-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-5+-drupal) (4)

If you're willing to simplify it quite a lot and lose some of the information you added, you might be able to use a shorter sentence like this one:

> To make a comparison, the questions tagged drupal (but not drupal-x) on Stack Overflow are 7,474, while the total number of questions tagged drupal-x (but not drupal) are 3,184.

[As a side note, I don't know what argument you're making, but you leave out mention of questions which are tagged *both* drupal and drupal-x; is this intentional?]

Comment: +1 Excellent layout. But I suspect what OP **means** is "By way of comparison there are: • 7,474 questions tagged *drupal* **but not** *drupal-5, -6* ...) and • 2 tagged *drupal-x* **but not** *drupal*, including ∘ 2 tagged *drupal-8* ∘ 2,062 tagged *drupal-7*, etc.

Comment: Two questions are tagged _drupal-8_, but not _drupal_. I am counting all the questions that are about Drupal.

Comment: I'm not even sure the (brackets) in my answer really count as "English". I certainly don't think a table does.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe not; I did preface my answer that it might not have been exactly what OP was looking for. But I decided to take the position that if I could help OP *express his meaning*, that could be useful, even if it's not strictly in sentence-form. Tbh I think it's a lot of information to cram into one sentence and that's part of the problem. If someone can figure out another way to write all of this in a coherent sentence I'll gladly upvote the answer :)

Comment: @ WendiKidd: So I guess the lack of any votes for my answer means you *don't* think it qualifies as a "coherent sentence"! :( To be honest, I think the question itself is rather pointless. The only connection to *English* I can see is that to convey the information *in words* with at least some level of "digestibility", you need to somehow combine repeated elements. But given the uncertainty over how questions with more than one "version-specific" tag might affect things, I think the whole concept is something of a no-hoper.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it means I'm tired and sometimes get distracted when leaving comments and forget to click the up arrow! You have a +1 now :) Sorry about that! Yeah, I think the sentence in question is pretty difficult to put into a shorter, cohesive sentence, but I can understand why the OP wanted help reducing it.

Comment: @ WendiKidd: Well if we treat it as a "real-world" problem, I suppose your table is the best approach. But imho that makes the question Off Topic anyway (which is how I'd voted before seriously considering a possible ***verbal*** answer). To my mind, the English language might be *capable* of being written down - but if you can't ***say*** it, it ain't "language" for the purposes of ELL.

Comment: To make it clear, what I am trying to achieve is avoiding not necessary words. For example, is the following sentence acceptable: "the questions tagged _drupal_ on Stack Overflow are 7,474; to those, you need to add 2 questions tagged _drupal-8_ [...]." Would be there any ambiguity in that? Since I am writing "you need to add," it should be obvious I am not counting the same questions twice.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Sorry, it's still not as obvious to me as you think it should be. Are there *any* questions tagged with both **drupal-7** and **drupal-8** (that *aren't* also tagged with **drupal**)? If so, how am I to know whether you included them under your counts for **drupal-7** or **drupal-8**, or perhaps didn't include them at all?

Comment: @FumbleFingers As with the other Stack Exchange tags, there is no restriction that doesn't allow you to use _drupal-N_ without _drupal_, or two _drupal-N_ tags without _drupal_. (Replace _N_ with a number between 5 and 8.) In most of the cases, _drupal_ is always used, as that merely means "this question is about Drupal." I am making assumptions, in order to simplify the way to count the number of Drupal questions. Differently, I should consider the questions tagged _drupal-views_ but not using _drupal_ or _drupal-N_, and do the same for every Drupal-related tag.

Comment: At that point, I could get questions that are not Drupal related. If I find just _drupal-views_ being used, how can I be sure it is a Drupal-related question without reading it? It could be the OP wanted to use _views_ but selected _drupal-views_, or somebody corrected _views_ with _drupal-views_ thinking it was the correct one.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I thoroughly understand your premise; I just can't think of a better way to word it that maintains the clarity. You concise suggestion is very ambiguous. It's difficult to apply conceptual restrictions and then try to write a simple sentence. There's just a lot of *content* you're trying to fit into a sentence, which isn't always easy. (Here's an idea; what if you tried writing the same sentence in your native language, could you come up with a way to simplify it then? There's no guarantee it would translate properly into English, but it might give us ideas?)

Comment: If I were to use Italian to write the same sentence, I would write something that is close to a translation of what I wrote in English.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, Wendikidd: I think we're drifting off the point when we start talking about the specific constraints of whatever original database queries produced OP's figures, and whether or not they're "ideal/adequate". In terms of *English **language***, all I can see being relevant here is that the word "respectively" can usefully be included in a shorter rephrasing. Everything else probably just amounts to *stylistic choices*, which I would say are inherently POB.